# If statement with rendering illusions before/after depending on position relative to set y point not working

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement, rendering

To be more clear this block started as a code for solely mainchar and Realchair so that when my character is above a certain y level it will give the illusion that he is behind the chair by rendering the character before the chair and if my character is under the set y level then he is rendered after the chair to give the illusion that he is in front of the chair.

ok but as you can see this is a switch because i have ImageTextureSide (mainchar facing right) and ImageTextureSideTwo (mainchar facing left), so i need to put this idea of the rendering illusion in both of the cases.

Now here is where the problem arises. I have multiple furniture assets in my project so i figured i would add the idea of the rendering illusion to Rightchair, but for some reason when i added the same logic, everything worked perfectly fine except for when mainchar.y < the set y value. In the case where it is less than the set y value it should be rendered before the chair which is what is written in the if statement for that situation. But only when i added the logic for the right chair is when mainchar.y < the set y value it renders the mainchar after the chair.

I added an image where you can see mainchar rendered after the chair despite the if statement running?

```
 switch (currentDirection) {
        case SideLeft:
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureglassybig, nullptr, &Glassy);

            if (mainchar.y > 250) {
                // Main character is above the chair, render chair first
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureChair, nullptr, &Realchair);
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureSideTwo, nullptr, &mainchar);
            }
            else {
                // Main character is below the chair, render main character first
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureSideTwo, nullptr, &mainchar);
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureChair, nullptr, &Realchair);
            }

            if (mainchar.y > 250) {
                // Main character is above the chair, render chair first
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureRChair, nullptr, &Rightchair);
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureSideTwo, nullptr, &mainchar);
            }
            else {
                // Main character is below the chair, render main character first
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureSideTwo, nullptr, &mainchar);
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureRChair, nullptr, &Rightchair);
            }
           
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureTChair, nullptr, &Topchair);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureTChair3, nullptr, &Topchair3);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTexturetable, nullptr, &Bigtable);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureBChair, nullptr, &Bottomchair);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureBChair2, nullptr, &Bottomchair2);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureRminitable, nullptr, &Minitbl);


            break;

        case SideRight:

            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureglassybig, nullptr, &Glassy);

            if (mainchar.y < 250) {
                // Main character is above the chair, render chair first
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureSide, nullptr, &mainchar);
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureChair, nullptr, &Realchair);

                cout << ("\n RIGHTif");
            }
            else {
                // Main character is below the chair, render main character first
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureChair, nullptr, &Realchair);
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureSide, nullptr, &mainchar);
                cout << ("RIGHTelse");

            }

            if (mainchar.y < 250) {
                // Main character is above the chair, render chair first
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureSide, nullptr, &mainchar);
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureRChair, nullptr, &Rightchair);

                cout << ("\n RIGHTif");
            }
            else {
                // Main character is below the chair, render main character first
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureRChair, nullptr, &Rightchair);
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureSide, nullptr, &mainchar);
                cout << ("RIGHTelse");

            }

            
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureTChair, nullptr, &Topchair);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureTChair3, nullptr, &Topchair3);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTexturetable, nullptr, &Bigtable);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureBChair, nullptr, &Bottomchair);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureBChair2, nullptr, &Bottomchair2);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureRminitable, nullptr, &Minitbl);







            break;

        }

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/897ap.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're rendering the main char *twice* in your code. Since the condition is exactly the same in both cases, combine them into a single case:

```
if (mainchar.y > 250) {
    // Main character is above the chair, render chair first
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureChair, nullptr, &Realchair);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureRChair, nullptr, &Rightchair);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureSideTwo, nullptr, &mainchar);
}
else {
    // Main character is below the chair, render main character first
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureSideTwo, nullptr, &mainchar);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureChair, nullptr, &Realchair);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imageTextureRChair, nullptr, &Rightchair);
}
```

Comment: im actually brain dead i love you